# Cannot erase, partition or reinstall - exit code 0 / exit code8

Tags: disk-utility, partition, ssd, intel

After erasing the main volume to prep my MBP i7 for a transfer of ownership I started  reinstalling macOS from recovery mode, but the wifi went down during download and I had to restart my mac as the process got stuck. And things started to get south from there.

I first had a lot of Volumes available, neither of repairable.

[image: volumes available]

[image: errors]

After trying several things I erased then the entire APFS group and tried to reinstall macOS but that errored again:

[image: error mac os]
[image]

The SSD:
[image: SSD]

I don't really know where to take it from there, any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Did you want to downgrade this to Sierra?  Also, it looks like you’ve selected the wrong drive, it should be the Apple SSD

Comment: No, I didn't try to downgrade. Sierra is what is given me to as an option by default when trying to re-install from recovery. The Apple SSD is not available in the Install macOS Sierra flow. Only have Apple Media.

Comment: Sierra won’t see any APFS containers.  How are you booting into recovery?

Comment: I am using the command + r shortcut. I have added another screenie showing the state of my SSD. But before this, the mac was on Monterey (or Ventura). Can't remember exactly, but one of the latest versions.

Comment: Strat by formatting it as HFS+.  If you want the latest, boot with Opt-Cmd-R

Comment: I will give that a try a tad later and will keep you posted. Thanks @Allan

Comment: That did the job, the mac is back on track. Thanks a bunch Allan 

Comment: Post and answer and I send an upvote your way.